# Update fields in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose, mern, mongodb-atlas

I have a collection stored in MongoDB Atlas as

Name of collection: users

.. a doc in the collection

```
{
  name: "Josh",
  email: "test1@gmail.com",
  categories: {
    finance: ["Link1", "Link2"],
    research: ["link2],
  }
```

}

I wish to make changes to this doc. Emails in my collections are unique
So, I used updateOne to make the changes as shown in many examples.

I want to build an API to add new categories. So, if the user wants to add a new category, say, as SCHOOL, a req is made from front end with the email of the user and the new category to be added in the req.body.

```
UserSchema.findOne({ email }, (err, user) => {
if (user) {
  var cats = user.categories;
  console.log(cats, "here");
  cats[newCat] = [];
  console.log(cats, "again here");
  UserSchema.updateOne({ email: email }, { $set: { categories: cats } });
  return res.status(200).json({ msg: "well done " });
}
```

});

This piece of code doesnt seem to make updates to the doc. I am not sure why, can any one shed some light?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `.` operator

```
UserSchema.updateOne({ email: email }, { $set: { "categories.school": cats } });
```